# How to run nested xargs commands?

Tags: multisite, wp-cli

I am trying to loop through all sites on a multisite network, and for each site, delete all *subscriber* users.  I have tried this WP-CLI command:

`wp site list --field=url | xargs -n 1 -I ^ wp user list --url=^ --role=subscriber --field=ID | xargs -n 2 -I % ^ wp user delete % --url=^ --reassign=4`

I can't find a way to pass the `^` value to the second xargs command.  Anyone?

Comment: that's a lot of piped/chained commands, does it have to be a one liner with pipes? Couldn't you use a bash variable or two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xargs is unnecessary, something similar to this will do the job without any piping or `xargs`:

```
sites=$(wp site list --field=url)
for site in $sites
do
  users=$(wp user list --url="$site" --role=subscriber)
  for user in $users
  do
    wp user delete $user --url="$site" --reassign=4
  end
end
```

Comment: Its been a while since I wrote a bash script, but why not?  This is the script that works for me (maybe you can't put in line breaks in a comment?):
`#!/bin/bash  
  
sites=$(wp site list --field=url)  
for site in $sites  
do  
  users=$(wp user list --url=$site --role=subscriber --field=ID)  
  for user in $users  
  do  
    wp user delete $user --url=$site --reassign=4  
  done  
done`